# Use window command prompt split text file

Tags: windows, cmd, command-prompt

I need to split a large text file in small text file,like i have 100 line in text file,then every 10 record split in new text file.In DOS have split function but in window cmd don't have split function.Anybody have solution in window cmd?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a scripting language like Python to do what you are trying to achieve. I don't think that there is a split command from CMD, alternatively use PowerShell which is bundled with Windows:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/9d508b61-f56a-43f4-ba38-95f9d869941d/powershell-splitting-a-string?forum=ITCG

Comment: The question is asking to split text file from win cmd

Answer (score 0):

You can use this batch script:

filesplit.bat

```
@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set /a i = 1, j = %2
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%1) do (
echo %%a>>!i!_%1
set /a j -= 1
if !j! EQU 0 set /a i += 1, j = %2
)
```

F.ex.:

filesplit myfile.txt 10

Now, batch isn't fast, so if the file to split is large this will take time. Better then to write a simple C program.

Comment: Can it print blank lines or lines starting with semicolon ';'?

Answer (score 0):

Split text file (max lines each):

```
: Initialize
set input=file.txt
set max=10

set /a line=1 >nul
set /a file=1 >nul
set out=!file!_%input%
set /a max+=1 >nul

echo Number of lines in %input%:
find /c /v "" < %input%

: Split file
for /f "tokens=* delims=[" %i in ('type "%input%" ^| find /v /n ""') do (

if !line!==%max% (
set /a line=1 >nul
set /a file+=1 >nul
set out=!file!_%input%
echo Writing file: !out!
)

REM Write next file
set a=%i
set a=!a:*]=]!
echo:!a:~1!>>!out!
set /a line+=1 >nul
)
```

Tested in Win 10 CMD